# Why does cout << &r give different output than cout << (void*)&r?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, char, cout

This might be a stupid question, but I'm new to C++ so I'm still fooling around with the basics. Testing pointers, I bumped into something that didn't produce the output I expected.

When I ran the following:

```
char r ('m');
cout << r << endl;
cout << &r << endl;
cout << (void*)&r << endl;
```

I expected this:

```
m
0042FC0F
0042FC0F
```

..but I got this:

```
m
m╠╠╠╠ôNh│hⁿB
0042FC0F
```

I was thinking that perhaps since `r` is of type `char`, `cout` would interpret `&r` as a `char*` and [for some reason] output the pointer value - the bytes comprising the address of `r` - as a series of `chars`, but then why would the first one would be `m`, the *content* of the address pointed to, rather than the `char` representation of the first byte of the pointer address.. It was as if `cout` interprets `&r` as `r` but instead of just outputting `'m'`, it goes on to output more chars - interpreted from the byte values of the subsequent 11 memory addresses.. Why? And why 11?

I'm using MSVC++ (Visual Studio 2013) on 64 bit Win7.

---

**Postscript:** I got a lot of correct answers here (as expected, given the trivial nature of the question). Since I can only accept one, I made it the first one I saw. But thanks, everyone.

So to summarize and expand on the instinctive theories mentioned in my question:

Yes, `cout` does interpret `&r` as `char*`, but since `char*` is a 'special thing' in C++ that essentially means *a null terminated string* (rather than *a pointer* [to a single `char`]), `cout` will attempt to print out that string by outputting chars (interpreted from the byte contents of the memory address of `r` onwards) until it encounters `'\0'`. Which explains the 11 extra characters (it just coincidentally took 11 more bytes to hit that `NUL`).

And for completeness - the same code, but with `int` instead of `char`, performs as expected:

```
int s (3);
cout << s << endl;
cout << &s << endl;
cout << (void*)&s << endl;
```

Produces:

```
3
002AF940
002AF940
```

Comment: char* is interpreted as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `char *` is a special thing in `C++`, inherited from `C`. It is, in most circumstances, a `C`-style string. It is supposed to point to an array of `char`s, terminated with a `0` (a NUL character, `'\0'`).

So it tries to print this, following on in to the memory after the `'m'`, looking for a terminating `'\0'`. This makes it print some random garbage. This is known as [*Undefined Behaviour*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

Comment: In this specific case, with this compiler on this platform, it prints random garbage.  It could also crash, appear to work correctly, play the Andy Griffith theme, or do any of a billion other things.  Undefined is undefined.  :)

Answer (score 2):

There is an `operator<<` overload specifically for `char*` strings.  This outputs the null-terminated string, not the address.  Since the pointer you're passing this overload *isn't* a null-terminated string, you also get Undefined Behavior when `operator<<` runs past the end of the buffer.

Conversely, the `void*` overload will print the address.

Answer (score 2):

Because `operator<<` is overloaded based on the data type.

If you give it a `char`, it assumes you want that character.

If you give it a `void*`, it assumes you want an address.

However, if you give it a `char*`, it takes that as a C-style string and attempts to output it as such. Since the original intent of C++ was "C with classes", handling of C-style strings was a necessity.

The reason you get all the rubbish at the end is simply because, despite your assertion to the compiler, it *isn't* actually a C-style string. Specifically, it is not guaranteed to have a string-terminating NUL character at the end so the output routines will just output whatever happens to be in memory after it.

This may work (if there's a NUL there), it may print gibberish (if there's a NUL nearby), or it may fall over spectacularly (if there's no NUL before it gets to memory it cannot read). It's *not* something you should rely on.

Answer (score 1):

Because there's an overload of `operator<<` which takes a `const char` pointer as it's second argument and prints out a string. The overload that takes a `void` pointer prints only the address.

Answer (score 0):

A `char *` is often - usually even - a pointer to a C-style null-terminated string (or a string literal) and is treated as such by ostreams. A `void *` by contrast unambiguously indicates a pointer value is required.

Answer (score 0):

The output operator (`operator<<()`)  is overloaded for `char const*` and `void const*`. When passing a `char*` the overload for `char const*` is a better match and chosen. This overload expects a pointer to the start of a null terminated string. You give it a pointer to an individual `char`, i.e., you get undefined behavior.

If you want to try with a well-defined example you can use

```
char s[] = { 'm', 0 };
std::cout << s[0] << '\n';
std::cout << &s[0] << '\n';
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(&s[0]) << '\n';
```